# Do I need to cancel StreamSubscriptions that don't assign to a variable?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, stream

Here are 2 different ways I can listen to a stream. The top one gives no IDE warning about cancelling a subscription. The bottom one does.

```
// No IDE warning about cancelling subscription
_loginBloc.state.listen((state) {});

// "Cancel instances of dart.async.StreamSubscription"
StreamSubscription s = _loginBloc.state.listen((state) {});
```

If I use the first method, do I need to cancel the subscription somehow, or will it dispose of itself?

Answer (score 1):

There is no behavior difference between these two. You are running in to a limitation of [the lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/cancel_subscriptions.html). That lint has a number of false positives and negatives.

In general if you *aren't* using the `StreamSubscription` returned from `listen` you should be using [`forEach`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-async/Stream/forEach.html) instead.

If you know that the `Stream` will end before whatever is listening doesn't care about it anymore there isn't any need to explicitly cancel. Where you want to be sure to cancel is if there is a point in time where the listener no longer cares about the result - say because it's a widget which is no longer being displayed.

Comment: I couldn't find a reference that says that you don't need to cancel if you know that the `Stream` will end before the listener needs to cancel. Where did you read that?

Comment: The Stream can do the same cleanup on "Done" as it would do on "Cancel" - it knows that no more events will be coming. Of course a stream _can_ leak memory even if there is a done or cancel - but the implementations in the SDK are safe.